# RailsEngine can't find jQuery when it can

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, rails-admin

I am using a RailsEngine: RailsAdmin, and on page load when navigating to the relevant URL I keep getting the following errors in the Chrome console (I get about 20 of these for all the libs used - each complaining it can't find $), and JS based functionality doesn't work:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

If I then type this into the console I get a result, proving jQuery is defined

```
$('body')
==> <body class="rails_admin>...</body>
```

Why am I getting false error messages?

Comment: Probably missed some sneaky config...

Answer (score 1):

Chrome developer tools uses `$(...)` as a selector.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector

What does `(window.jQuery)` return?

*Lee answers: It returns function ( selector, context ) {...*

Huh. That's strange. Just to be sure, does `$(body)` return this:

`><body>...</body>`

or this:

```
[
><body>...</body>
]
```

The first would be Chrome Command Line return, but jQuery would return the second.

Also, I'm curious as to what `(window.$)` returns.

Comment: It returns ```function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
 }```

Comment: That's definitely jQuery loaded. I'd check to make sure jQuery is loading before any dependent libraries. I added some more tests at the end of my answer if you're so inclined.

Comment: (window.$) returns ```undefined```